# How to verify the text style in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, text-editor, rich-text-editor

I am developing an simple text editor in android with few basic options like bold, italic, bold+italic, underline strike through. Here is the code that I've used for applying the effects to the selected text when the corresponding button is clicked.

```
public void buttonClick(View target){
    Log.i("Information  ", "In click");
    View parentView = (View) target.getParent();
    final EditText editorField = (EditText) parentView.findViewById(R.id.editor_field);
    int startSelection = editorField.getSelectionStart();
    int endSelection = editorField.getSelectionEnd();
    Spannable textEdit = editorField.getText();

    if(target.getId() == R.id.boldButton){
        textEdit.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), startSelection, endSelection, 0);
    } else if(target.getId() == R.id.italicButton){
        textEdit.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC), startSelection, endSelection, 0);
    } else if(target.getId() == R.id.underlineButton){
        textEdit.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), startSelection, endSelection, Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
    } else if(target.getId() == R.id.strikeButton){
        textEdit.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), startSelection, endSelection, Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
    } else if(target.getId() == R.id.boldItalicButton){
        textEdit.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC), startSelection, endSelection, 0);
    } 
}
```

But before applying the text effect I have to check whether the selected text already have any text effect or not. i.e. Initially the selected text is in bold, so when bold button is clicked then that text effect must be removed. I don't understand how to do this. Could any one help me.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of styles calling the getSpans() method:

```
StyleSpan[] styleSpans = textEdit.getSpans(startSelection, endSelection, StyleSpan.class);
```

And then use the methods of the StyleSpan class:

```
if (styleSpans[i].getStyle() == android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD){
    ...  
}
```